# Delphi XE2 EnumWindows not working properly

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

Using Delphi XE2 update 3 or update 4 on Win7 64 bit.

Calling enumwindows does not work like it used to work in Delphi 6.

In Delphi 6 enumwindows processed windows until the callback function returned False. That is what the documentation says it should do:

"To continue enumeration, the callback function must return TRUE; to stop enumeration, it must return FALSE."

Making a call to enumwindows as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumWindows(@FindMyWindow,0);
  if GLBWindowHandle <> 0 then begin
    ShowMessage('found');
  end;
end;
```

Here is the callback function:

```
function FindMyWindow(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): boolean; stdcall;
var TheText : array[0..150] of char;
str : string;
begin
Result := True;
GLBWindowHandle := 0;
if (GetWindowText(hWnd, TheText, 150) <> 0) then
   begin
   str := TheText;
   if str = 'Form1' then
      begin
      GLBWindowHandle := hWnd;
      Result := False;
      end
   else
      result := True;
   end;
end;
```

Just to be clear the callback function is defined in code BEFORE the buttonclick event so it is found by the compiler without needing to be defined in the interface section.

If this is run using Delphi 6 the enumeration of windows stops once the False result is returned and GLBWindowHandle is not zero

If this is run using Delphi XE2 the enumeration continues after the False result is returned and GLBWindowHandle is always zero.

WTF? Anybody have any ideas why the enumeration is not stopping like the documentation states it should and how it used to in Delphi 6?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you verified that `GLBWindowHandle` gets set and then reset, or is it also possible that it doesn't get set at all?

Comment: Yes, it is set and then reset.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior if you compile for 32 bits and 64 bits?

Comment: We are only compiling for 32bits at the moment. I have not tested the 64 bit compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This declaration is incorrect:

```
function FindMyWindow(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): boolean; stdcall;
```

It should be:

```
function FindMyWindow(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
```

You have to be careful not to mix up `Boolean` and `BOOL` since they are not the same thing. The former is a single byte, the latter is 4 bytes. This mismatch between what `EnumWindows` expects and what your callback function delivers is enough to cause the behaviour you observe.

---

In addition, Rob Kennedy contributed this excellent comment:

> The compiler can help find this error if you get out of the habit of using the `@` operator before the function name when you call `EnumWindows`. If the function signature is compatible, the compiler will let you use it without `@`. Using `@` turns it into a generic pointer, and that's compatible with everything, so the error is masked by unnecessary syntax. In short, using `@` to create function pointers should be considered a *code smell*.

---

**Discussion**

Unfortunately the `Windows.pas` header translation defines `EnumWindows` in a most unhelpful manner, like this:

```
function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: TFNWndEnumProc; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Now, the problem is in the definition of `TFNWndEnumProc`. It is defined as:

```
TFarProc = Pointer;
TFNWndEnumProc = TFarProc;
```

This means that you *have* to use the `@` operator to make a generic pointer, because the function needs a generic pointer. If `TFNWndEnumProc` were declared like this:

```
TFNWndEnumProc = function(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
```

then the compiler would have been able to find the error.

```
type
  TFNWndEnumProc = function(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;

function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: TFNWndEnumProc;
  lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32';

function FindMyWindow(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

....
EnumWindows(FindMyWindow, 0);
```

The compiler rejects the call to `EnumWindows` with the following error:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(38): E2010 Incompatible types: 'LongBool' and 'Boolean'

I think I will QC this issue and try my luck at persuading Embarcadero to stop using `TFarProc`.

Comment: I guess you just get lucky in D6. I didn't get as far as trying to work out the exact reason why behaviour changes.

Comment: A number of things seem to have happened over the years to the internals of the compiler that have such seemingly odd effects.  f.i see my own answer to my own question (that had me stumped for almost a YEAR)  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482699/zeroconf-bonjour-code-that-works-in-delphi-7-not-working-in-2009)

Comment: The compiler can help find this error if you get out of the habit of using the `@` operator before the function name when you call `EnumWindows`. If the function signature is compatible, the compiler will let you use it without `@`. Using `@` turns it into a generic pointer, and that's compatible with everything, so the error is masked by unnecessary syntax. In short, using `@` to create function pointers should be considered a *code smell*.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I don't follow... you mean calling `EnumWindows` e.g. `EnumWindows(FindMyWindow, 0)`? (that wont compile at all).

Comment: @Kobik, it should compile if the callback function signature matches.

Comment: Tested with D5/D7/D2009. result: `Not enough actual parameters`

Comment: @rob Sadly the windows header translations in Windows.pas let us down here.

Comment: Excellent comment quoted actually smells w/o rewriting Windows.pas and/or having Borkadero to do so. Or the wheel reinvention which finally happened.

Comment: @user539484 Translating a couple of API calls isn't that challenging for a proficient coder. If you are finding it hard I'm sure we could help you with that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, in the fact "couple" is "a whole bunch of them, really" :-) And amount of time is challenging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, a whole wall of text brought from the side notes is not useful water. You answer is very deep :-)

Comment: I know it's a long shot but I'm really struggling to get this working on Windows8 and XE3 update 2... It's an old piece of code which has been migrated from Delphi5. When EnumWindows runs it does the callback seemingly OK until it eventually locks up. If I create a new test app with the same calls then that works OK. Have doubled checked BOOL types are correct but the old unit just won't work so there must be something in the project changing something...any ideas very welcome!

Comment: @sergeantKK Create a small project that demonstrates the fault, and post it into a new question.

Comment: @David Heffernan That's what I considered doing but if I create a new project there is no problem...I'm currently extracting bits of code into a newly created unit to see if that works within the updated (old) project and if not will it work in a new project. I'm guessing it's to do with compiler options or unit paths...

Comment: @David Heffernan I have tracked down why the callback was hanging...it was hanging up in the call to GetWindowText which I had inside the EnumWindows callback. Win8 hung up when trying to GetWindowText for the application's own window handle. Putting a check in to not check it's own application title has fixed my issue :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I just came across the TFarProc issue myself, and it's not fixed in XE4. Do you have a link to the QC report you filed, please? I'd like to upvote it.

Comment: @DavidM It doesn't look like I did QC it. I suspect it will never be changed.

Comment: This issue has been giving me weird bugs for 2 years now!!!! If i could upvote a million times. I so would, I never expected this to be the problem. Some compiles worked fine, especially debug mode was stable then in production some release compiles would just not get the right result when enumerating windows. Thank you David