# How does Delphi resolve overloaded functions with integral parameters?

Tags: delphi

Consider the following program:

```
program IntegerOverloads;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure WordOrCardinal(Value: Word); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Word');
end;

procedure WordOrCardinal(Value: Cardinal); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Cardinal');
end;

procedure SmallintOrInteger(Value: Smallint); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Smallint');
end;

procedure SmallintOrInteger(Value: Integer); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Integer');
end;

procedure ShortintOrSmallint(Value: Shortint); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Shortint');
end;

procedure ShortintOrSmallint(Value: Smallint); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Smallint');
end;

procedure Main;
var
  _integer: Integer;
  _cardinal: Cardinal;
  _word: Word;
begin
  WordOrCardinal(_Integer);
  SmallintOrInteger(_cardinal);
  ShortintOrSmallint(_word);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

The output when compiled by XE2 is:

```
Cardinal
Integer
Smallint
```

The output when compiled by Delphi 6 is:

```
Word
Smallint
Shortint
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) states (emphasis mine):

> You can pass to an overloaded routine parameters that are not
>   identical in type with those in any of the routine's declarations, but
>   that are assignment-compatible with the parameters in more than one
>   declaration. This happens most frequently when a routine is overloaded
>   with different integer types or different real types - for example:
>
> ```
> procedure Store(X: Longint); overload;
> procedure Store(X: Shortint); overload;
> ```
>
> In these cases, when it is possible to do so without ambiguity, the
>   compiler invokes the routine whose parameters are of the **type with the
>   smallest range that accommodates the actual parameters in the call**.

But that does seem to apply here. None of the procedure calls in the example code accept a type that accommodates the actual parameters in the call.

I cannot find any documentation that describes what rule the compiler follows. Can anyone point me to such documentation?

This question was prompted by the following articles:

- [ReverseBytes()](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=1233)
- [ZeroConf/Bonjour Code that works in Delphi 7 not working in 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482699/zeroconf-bonjour-code-that-works-in-delphi-7-not-working-in-2009)
- [What's in a Word ... ?](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/?p=1240)

---

#### Update

Prompted by Ken White's comments, I wrote another program to illustrate some more oddities:

```
program IntegerOverloadsPart2;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure Test(Value: Byte); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Byte');
end;

procedure Test(Value: Word); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Word');
end;

procedure Test(Value: Cardinal); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Cardinal');
end;

procedure Test(Value: Uint64); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Uint64');
end;

procedure Main;
var
  _byte: Byte;
  _shortint: Shortint;
  _word: Word;
  _smallint: Smallint;
  _cardinal: Cardinal;
  _integer: Integer;
  _uint64: UInt64;
  _int64: Int64;
begin
  Writeln('Unsigned variables passed as parameters:');
  Test(_byte);
  Test(_word);
  Test(_cardinal);
  Test(_uint64);
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Signed variables passed as parameters:');
  Test(_shortint);
  Test(_smallint);
  Test(_integer);
  Test(_int64);
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

When compiled by XE2 the output is:

```
Unsigned variables passed as parameters:
Byte
Word
Cardinal
Uint64

Signed variables passed as parameters:
Uint64
Uint64
Uint64
Uint64
```

On Delphi 6 I have to remove the `UInt64` overload since that type does not exist on Delphi 6 the output is:

```
Unsigned variables passed as parameters:
Byte
Word
Cardinal

Signed variables passed as parameters:
Byte
Byte
Byte
```

Again neither behaviour looks consistent with the statement that:

> In these cases, when it is possible to do so without ambiguity, the
>   compiler invokes the routine whose parameters are of the **type with the
>   smallest range that accommodates the actual parameters in the call**.

Comment: How do you interpret "range"? If you see it as "Word and Smallint both have 65536 different values", then the XE2 output matches the documentation. If you see it as "Word has a range from 0 to 65535, Smallint has a range from -32768 to 32767", then as far as I can tell there is no correct answer based on the documentation you linked to.

Comment: @hvd My interpretation is the second one that you describe.

Comment: +1. Nice question. I thought at first it had to do with different values assigned to each of the variables, but some experimentation with them shows that isn't the case. (Assigning a very small value to `_word` does not change it's size from `SmallInt`, and a very large value leaves it unchanged as well.) I wonder if this is related to changes made for 32/64 bit support?

Comment: @KenWhite Overloads are resolved at compile time and its the *type* of the parameter that determines which overload is chosen. I gather the compiler changed behaviour at D2009.

Comment: @David, I'm aware of that; your sample code didn't include any assignments, so I was presuming you'd set some values prior to compiling, and those would have been available at compile-time.

Comment: @Ken I intentionally did not assign the values because I never read them. I wanted to bring out the point that it was the compile time resolution that is at issue.

Comment: Looks like a silent type coercion that causes data loss,  in the Delphi 6 through 2007 compilers was quietly fixed in Delphi 2009. :-)

Comment: @WarrenP It seems broken in all versions to me. How do you choose which type to coerce to? Of course, you would be asking for trouble ever to write overloads like this. Especially with Pascal's shockingly slack type system.

Comment: @ken "I thought at first it had to do with
different values assigned to each of the variables" That raises an interesting topic. Data flow analysis. The Delphi compiler does none. So if you write i := 1; if i > 0 then   the compiler will check the inequality at runtime. The compiler simply does not do data flow analysis. I think that's no bad thing. No criticism at all.

Comment: Actually, the XE2 behavior makes sense; I think earlier versions were wrong. Calling `WordOrCardinal` with an `Integer`, which is 32-bit, should call the `Cardinal` version barring any compile-time information about the value, as a 32-bit `Integer` can't be presumed to fit into a 16-bit `Word`. The same applies to `ShortintOrSmallInt(_word)`, where a 16-bit `Word` can't possibly be assumed to fit into an 8-bit `ShortInt`, so it resolves to `SmallInt` instead. It may result in a runtime range check or overflow exception, but at compile time there's no value to consider. Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 @KenWhite, that makes tons of sense since the introduction of x64 compiling. The 64bit capabilities have apparently slowly been introduced in prior version of Delphi, then in XE2, they made the final adjustments and made the switch.

Comment: I'm hoping someone with the team who develops the Delphi Compiler will drop in for a nice detailed answer...

Comment: @Jerry: I don't think it is specifically to do with 64-bit per se; I think it's more related to the compiler re-design to support 64-bit, and code changes in the compiler fixed this long standing issue as a by-product. (If it was intentional, they would have mentioned it in the docs like they did the breaking change about `with` and read-only record properties in D2010.) Maybe Allen Bauer will see this and comment or answer; he's on the compiler team and has been here quite often, but whether he'll post on it or not...

Comment: @Ken I disagree with your view that the one behaviour is preferable to the other. An Integer does not fit inside a Cardinal. For me this code should produce "no matching overload found" compile errors. That's how I read the documentation.

Comment: @Ken In fact, the compiler is happy to accept an Int64 as parameter to  any of these functions. So, data type size doesn't have to match. In that case, today's compiler selects the overload with the largest data type. Note also that `SmallintOrInteger(_word)` results in the output `Integer`. Here the compiler selects an overload where the parameter does accommodate the range of values.

Comment: @Ken I expanded the question with some more findings.

Comment: The compiler has always been a bit fast and loose with "integer <--> cardinal" coercion. From a raw binary point of view, yes, they do fit, if you don't care about the fact that $FFFFFFFF means something different in each one.

Comment: @Warren The output of my second program knocks that argument over

Comment: Oh. The signed to UINT64 is particularly perplexing.

Answer (score 2):

Neither unsigned type can accommodate a signed type; the documentation quoted is consistent with your examples - it just says nothing about how the compiler will treat them. On the other hand a signed type can accommodate an unsigned type (SmallInt accomodates Byte, LongInt accomodates Word, Int64 accomodates Cardinal):

```
program IntegerOverloadsPart3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure Test(Value: ShortInt); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Short');
end;

procedure Test(Value: SmallInt); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Small');
end;

procedure Test(Value: LongInt); overload;
begin
  Writeln('Long');
end;

procedure Test(Value: Int64); overload;
begin
  Writeln('64');
end;

procedure Main;
var
  _byte: Byte;
  _word: Word;
  _cardinal: Cardinal;
  _uint64: UInt64;
begin
  Writeln('Unsigned variables passed as parameters:');
  Test(_byte);
  Test(_word);
  Test(_cardinal);
  Test(_uint64);
  Writeln;
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

Delphi XE output:

```
Small
Long
64
64
```

Comment: Yes, it all makes sense that way round, passing unsigned variables to procedures which take signed parameters. It's the other way around that is troublesome.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - if you are writing overloads why not to write some more (for signed types) to remove all ambiguities?

Comment: I'm not writing code like this. I consider it to be a minefield. Jolyon's blog articles got me thinking and I'd like to understand why the compiler behaves as it does.

Comment: yes it is a minefield, and it will remain a minefield even if a compiler engineer will explain why the compiler behaves so.