# How does Delphi resolve overloaded functions with Pointer(typeless one) parameters?

Tags: arrays, delphi, pointers, overloading, overload-resolution

Below are few overloaded functions. 
Try to guess which function of those would get called.

```
program Project2;
    {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Types, SysUtils;

procedure Some(const Buf); overload;
  begin
    Writeln('const-typeless')
  end;

//procedure Some(var Buf); overload;
//  begin
//    Writeln('var-typeless')
//  end;

//procedure Some(Buf :TByteDynArray); overload;
//  begin
//    Writeln('Byte dynamic array');
//  end;

procedure Some(Buf :array of Byte); overload;
  begin
    Writeln('Byte open array');
  end;

procedure Some(Buf :TArray<Byte>); overload;
  begin
    Writeln('TBytes AKA byte generic array');
  end;

//procedure Some(Buf :TBytes); overload;
//  begin
//    Writeln('TBytes AKA byte generic array');
//  end;

var p: pointer;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    WriteLn ('Calling overloaded procedure with Pointer parameter:');

    Write('  * nil: '); p := nil; Some(p);
    Write('  * garbage: '); p := Pointer(1); Some(p);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

In fact, the 2nd one is called and throws AV on its 2nd call.
Given old VCL pattern of using `Pointer` and `Integer` interchangeably (such as `TList` and `TStrings.Objects` and `TWinControl.Tag`) that may cause unexpected AVs on a rather regular code.

*{$T+}* does not change the behavior, so it was not that Delphi thinks `^Byte` is `Pointer.`

However declaring `p: PInteger;` fixes it. Also the open-array variant is not called for pointer, and is treated/name-mangled differently than generic-array variant. Dynamic array is name-mangled differently from generic array, so both can be used, yet at the call site *ambiguous overload* error would happen if both uncommented. However, if to compile with generic array disabled and dinamic array uncommented - the same weird behavior happens.

Why does the compiler resolve to dynamic/generic array when parameter is a `Pointer`, and resolve to constant typeless when parameter is `PInteger` ?

- Related: [How does Delphi resolve overloaded functions with integral parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526786)
- Related: [why two aliases to "array of string" treated differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029353)
- Related: [QC 108978](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108978)
- Code from: http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=970289

PS. Opened [QC 109019](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109019)

Comment: Are you posting a question or a bug? If it is the latter case, there is Quality Central for that...

Comment: @MadHatter for now it is a question. If no reasonable explanation found - then that might be bug.

Comment: You can run the code to find out which one gets called. If you do that then we don't need to. Clearly you have done but you didn't tell us what the result is. As it stands this question is not complete. What you mean to ask is "Why does the compiler resolve to dynamic array when parameter is a `Pointer`, and resolve to constant typeless when parameter is `PInteger`"? I suggest you fix the question.

Comment: Just a guess - dynamic array is a pointer, but not PInteger; hence the compiler prefers dynarray overload for a pointer parameter and const for PInteger. Bad if such overloads are now in VCL code.

Comment: @Serg; With default {$T-} state, PInteger is pointer. And if it is not, then PByte is not Pointer either. They are in VCL XE3 code - see QC link.

Comment: PInteger is a pointer, but PInteger is not a dynarray. I could see no reason why the compiler should call dynarray overload for PInteger argument, but I could see reasons why it calls dynarray overload for pointer argument.

Comment: @Arioch, PInteger is never Pointer, even in $T- mode. In $T- mode, it's the expression `@IntVar` that has type Pointer. It doesn't affect the compatibility of things that are already typed pointers.

Comment: **Never ever write such code** that has a reader/maintainer second guess what the compiler will do depending on switches or obscure/undocumented decision tree. Overloaded routines can be a pain already when there is no signature ambiguity, here you have a recipe for a disaster. My 2¢...

Comment: @François Good Point. Tell Embarcadero this... But they'd probably would answer they are maintainers, not we.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no documentation for this, so the best we can do is poke at the compiler and try to guess the reasoning behind its behaviour.

Now, a procedure with a typeless parameter can be passed any parameter, irrespective of its type. So, any sane overload resolution scheme has to consider the typeless parameter last, only when it has exhausted all other possible candidates. Otherwise it would always be chosen.

So with that, the behaviour can be explained.

- When your parameter is of type, `Pointer`, that is assignment compatible with a dynamic array. Which means that the dynamic array overload can be selected.
- When your parameter is any other pointer type, it is not assignment compatible with a dynamic array. And so the overload resolution falls back to the final possible candidate, the typeless parameter.

Ultimately this behaviour comes down to the fact that the compiler considers `Pointer` to be assignment compatible with any dynamic array. That this statement is fact is easy to confirm by experiment, however, I cannot find documentation for it.

Comment: [Documentation for $T](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types#Type-checked_Pointers) mentions that the type of `@` expressions may be an "untyped pointer that is compatible with all other pointer types." From that we may infer that untyped pointers are compatible with all other pointer types, although another interpretation is that untyped pointers are only compatible with other pointer types when in $T- mode. That interpretation would be wrong, though.

Comment: @Rob Untyped pointers are always compatible with all other pointers. $T controls whether @ operator returns typed or untyped pointer. I think. Quite how dynamic arrays are pointer types, I'm not really sure. Do you know about that?

Comment: Oh, darn. I went looking for documentation that said untyped pointers were compatible with all pointer types, but forgot that what I really needed documentation that untyped pointers are compatible with dynamic-array types. I know dynamic arrays can be assigned to Pointer, and that Pointer can be assigned to dynamic arrays, but I don't know where it's documented, either. $T is irrelevant to this question, except that it's where that Pointer is compatible with all pointer types. If only we could link that dynamic arrays count as pointer types.

Comment: I'd rather have the compiler throw a warning than finding a way to resolve the ambiguity/overlap between the overloaded signatures.

Comment: @David there was that weird trick to dispose dynarrays by assigning to nil, like you can do with interfaces and cannot with strings. In Scala this was made safe by extracting Nil into common pointer-root type, that is parent to all reference types and that can only have Nil value. But Delphi lacks this NilPointer type and that implies compiler should have "special case" magic to make arrays assignment-compatible with nil and nothing else. This time magic seems to break out of its containment and became unexpected generic rule.

Comment: @Rob frankly i never could understand why that hacky *dynarray:=nil* was devised at all. Maybe the only valid reason was "beauty" of *if Assigned(dynarray) then...* at the price of placing landmines like this into VCL core.

Comment: Here is snippet that hints into this issue, but with very vague and ambiguous words: *Dynamic-array variables are implicitly pointers and are managed by the same reference-counting technique used for long strings. To deallocate a dynamic array, assign nil to a variable that references the array or pass the variable to Finalize; either of these methods disposes of the array, provided there are no other references to it. Dynamic arrays are automatically released when their reference-count drops to zero. Dynamic arrays of length 0 have the value nil.*

Comment: *Do not apply the dereference operator (^) to a dynamic-array variable or pass it to the New or Dispose procedure.* http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays  It does not talk about Poitners explicitly, but nil referenced and "implicitly pointers" were stated. Looks like classic "That's not a bug, that's a feature" attitude.